# Visualizing flow through graph networks

Tags: matlab, graph, networkx, graph-visualization

I've a graph network that has been created using MATLAB's graph function.

```
N = 10;
tail = 1:9;
head = 2:10;
G = graph(tail,head);
```

I could create the same graph using Networkx too.
However, I am not sure how to visualize flows through the network. For instance,
the times series data of values at all nodes are present in the following format.

```
data.time = 1:10;
data.values = rand(10,10);
```

I would like to ask for suggestions on tools that can be used to visualize the time series data
as dynamic change in values at the respective nodes.

Comment: This question seems a bit broad. When you say *visualize the time series data as dynamic change in values* do you have in mind an animation where the labels or graphical properties of the graph (e.g. line width or point size or colour) change with time?

Comment: @nekomatic Many thanks for the reply. I'm interested in visualizing the change in color of the node with time.

Comment: The help shows [how to change the appearance of the edges or nodes](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.html) and [how to create animations](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/animation-techniques-1.html), have you tried this?

Comment: @nekomatic I'll give it a try. I have used these options for adjusting linewidths of edges previously. However, I am not sure how to go about for the nodes.